# Prove that the Cardinality of $| \Bbb R \times \Bbb Z |$ has the same cardinality of $\Bbb R$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that $| \Bbb R \times \Bbb Z | = |\Bbb R|$

So I know I have to prove that there exists a bijective function between 
$\Bbb R \times \Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb R$. How I would do that, I don't know. I also know the Cardinality of $\Bbb R$ is the same as $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$

Comment: Have you heard the Cantor-Bernstein theorem?

Comment: Ever had a tasty cardinal sandwich?

Comment: $| \mathbb R | \leq | \mathbb R \times \mathbb Z | \leq | \mathbb R \times \mathbb R |$

Comment: @tetori, I haven't. I've heard of the Schroeder-Bernstein theorem

Comment: @youngpadawan That is same as I mentioned.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it in two ways (at least):

1. You can note that $\Bbb{|R|\leq|R\times Z|\leq|R\times R|}$, and apply some general theorems on cardinals.
2. You can note that $\Bbb R$ and $[0,1)$ have a bijection between them, so you're really looking at $[0,1)\times\Bbb Z$ in terms of cardinality. Now use your imagination to write down a bijection with $\Bbb R$.

Comment: What would that bijection be?

Comment: What would what bijection be?

Comment: The bijection between (0,1] x Z to R

Comment: It wouldn't be fair if I gave you all the answers. Would it?

Answer (score 2):

For $x\in\Bbb R$ let $k(x)$ be the greatest integer such that $[2k(x)+1]\pi\le x$.

The function $f(x)=(k(x),\tan x)$ is a bijection between $\Bbb R\setminus\{(2k+1)\pi:k\in\Bbb Z\}$ and $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb R$.

Now it suffices to show that $\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb N$ and $\Bbb R$ have the same cardinality.